# How to use Ionic 2 Push plugin with Amazon and GCM?

Tags: typescript, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, ionic2, amazon-sns

I'm developing an Angular 2/Ionic2 application which must receive and send push messages using Amazon SNS+Google Cloud Message on Mobile Devices (Android at first moment).

The problem here is that I cannot find any documentation, examples or tutorials about the use them together.

Can someone give-me an example of how to do this?